# Displaying a tree in ASCII

Tags: python, tree

As a time-pass activity, I decided to implement a [Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29)(like) structure in python.
I implemented a `Node` class (which alone serves the purpose here) like so:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, parent, *data):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.is_root = False

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Node '+repr(self.name)

    def dic(self):
        retval = {self:[]}
        for i in self.children:
            retval[self].append(i.dic())
        return retval

    def display(self): # Here
        pass

    def has_children(self):
        return bool(self.children)

    def get_parent(self):
        return self.parent

    def add_child(self, name, *data):
        child = Node(name, self,*data)
        self.children.append(child)
        return child
```

As you can see the `display` function is not implemented.
Here's an example tree.

```
A = Node('A',Node)
A.is_root = True
B = A.add_child('B')
D = B.add_child('D')
C = A.add_child('C')
E = C.add_child('E')
F = C.add_child('F')
G = C.add_child('G')
```

Here's some sample output for `display`.

```
>>> A.display()
    A
  +-^-+
  B   C
  | +-+-+
  D E F G
>>> C.display()
   C
 +-+-+
 E F G
```

In the shortest form,
**How can I "build" an ASCII tree (like above) from the Node class??**

In a longer form,
The "Logic" of printing is:

1. When there is only one child, `|` is put above the child. (D)
2. Else, Every child has a `+` above it, (B,C,E,F)
3. When there are even no. of children, `^` is put below the parent. (A)
4. Else, (there are odd no. of children) `+` is put below the parent. (C)

I have been thinking of starting from below. 
I realized that there has to be a call to the each of the children, but have been unable to implement anything (of that sorts or otherwise) that gave anything close to it.

Comment: If this is an exercise you should really attempt it by yourself, you will learn much better

Comment: "[Drawing presentable trees](http://billmill.org/pymag-trees/)" by Bill Mill is what I used a few weeks ago when I had a similar problem. It goes from a basic algorithm and adds restrictions on some properties the result has to comply to, adding complexity on several steps. It's a great article, and the examples are pretty much "generic". Check it out.

Comment: @jamylak This is a self given "exercise", So, I don't think asking this question, will hamper my skills or learning.. And, I have many broken tries too. Also, Read the first line...

Comment: @Schoolboy The article basically solves the problem of assigning `(x, y)` coordinates to the nodes of the tree. You then have a new (hopefully) simpler problem to solve to obtain the final output: given a set of nodes and their coordinates create an ASCII string that represents them. The first thing I'd do is to choose a unit size for `x` and `y`, find a convention for how to draw nodes and arcs and check, by hand, how the results are. Then you have to automize the drawing.

Comment: You can also use the asciitree package from https://github.com/mbr/asciitree or at least see how he implemented it.

Comment: I wanted to have a vertical tree, rather than an horizontal one... Which is why I asked this question. (I knew about the package)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a solution that covers most of what you're looking for.

Like any tree algorithm, recurse down the children of the tree, and combine results at each node.  Here's the trick: `display()` returns a rectangle of text, for example:

```
aaaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaa
```

Most of the rectangle will be whitespace.  Returning only rectangles of text makes it easy to combine results.  We'll use the following two helper functions, one to measure block widths, and the other to combine blocks horizontally into larger blocks:

```
def block_width(block):
    try:
        return block.index('\n')
    except ValueError:
        return len(block)

def stack_str_blocks(blocks):
    """Takes a list of multiline strings, and stacks them horizontally.

    For example, given 'aaa\naaa' and 'bbbb\nbbbb', it returns
    'aaa bbbb\naaa bbbb'.  As in:

    'aaa  +  'bbbb   =  'aaa bbbb
     aaa'     bbbb'      aaa bbbb'

    Each block must be rectangular (all lines are the same length), but blocks
    can be different sizes.
    """
    builder = []
    block_lens = [block_width(bl) for bl in blocks]
    split_blocks = [bl.split('\n') for bl in blocks]

    for line_list in itertools.izip_longest(*split_blocks, fillvalue=None):
        for i, line in enumerate(line_list):
            if line is None:
                builder.append(' ' * block_lens[i])
            else:
                builder.append(line)
            if i != len(line_list) - 1:
                builder.append(' ')  # Padding
        builder.append('\n')

    return ''.join(builder[:-1])
```

See where this is going?  Children return a rectangle that displays themselves and their descendants, and each node will combine these rectangles into a larger rectangle that contains itself.  The rest of the code just renders the dashes and pluses:

```
class Node:
    def display(self): # Here
        if not self.children:
            return self.name

        child_strs = [child.display() for child in self.children]
        child_widths = [block_width(s) for s in child_strs]

        # How wide is this block?
        display_width = max(len(self.name),
                    sum(child_widths) + len(child_widths) - 1)

        # Determines midpoints of child blocks
        child_midpoints = []
        child_end = 0
        for width in child_widths:
            child_midpoints.append(child_end + (width // 2))
            child_end += width + 1

        # Builds up the brace, using the child midpoints
        brace_builder = []
        for i in xrange(display_width):
            if i < child_midpoints[0] or i > child_midpoints[-1]:
                brace_builder.append(' ')
            elif i in child_midpoints:
                brace_builder.append('+')
            else:
                brace_builder.append('-')
        brace = ''.join(brace_builder)

        name_str = '{:^{}}'.format(self.name, display_width)
        below = stack_str_blocks(child_strs)

        return name_str + '\n' + brace + '\n' + below

    # SNIP (your other methods)
```

And we're off to the races!

```
                             a                             
+-+-+---------------------------+                          
b e f                           g                          
+     +-+-------------------------+                        
c     h i                         k                        
+       + +-+-+-+-------------+-------------+-+------+     
d       j l m p r             s             O P      Q     
            + +   +-+-+-+---------+             +-----+    
            n q   t u w x         y             R     S    
            +       +     +-------+-------+       +---+---+
            o       v     z       A       M       T   U   Z
                            +-+-+-+-+-+-+ +           +   +
                            B D E H I K L N           V   a
                            +   +   +               +-+-+ +
                            C   F   J               W X Y b
                                +                          
                                G
```

(Requirements like "placing a ^ below the parent" are left as an exercise for the reader)

Comment: Wow, Great thanks a lot, I was not expecting an answer to come by after such a long time.. Wonderful.. Thanks a  lot for this, great logic!! Deserves more votes!!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest to take a look at ETE module http://ete.cgenomics.org which implements the functionality you describe here and much more.

At the same time, I'd like to provide this entry [Pretty Print output in a sideways tree format in console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255793/pretty-print-output-in-a-sideways-tree-format-in-console-window/17260252#17260252) where a similar question has been asked before. As you can see in such discussion, the _asciiArt function from ETE provides what, I think, you are looking for.

I hope this helps,