# I have a python dictionary where i need to find the children of the nodes if available

Tags: python, dictionary, parent, children

I have the following dictionary representing `id:parent. {1: 2, 3: 1}`.

I need to loop and check if `id == parent` then it is a child.

For example here:
`1=1` so `3` is the child of `1`.

I will append it to the dictionary accordingly. 
   Any ideas?

```
 d={1:2, 3:1}
      for node in d:
```

Comment: so you want to make a new dict of `id:child`

Comment: yes, or append the child to the original dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1={1:2,2:3,3:1,4:1,5:2}
result={}
for key in dict1.keys():
    result[key]=[]
    for item in dict1.items():
        if key==item[1]:
            result[key].append(item[0])
print(result)  

output:
   {1: [3, 4], 2: [1, 5], 3: [2], 4: [], 5: []}
```

If you don't want to have those ids with no child, then you can write in the following way.

```
dict1={1:2,2:3,3:1,4:1,5:2}
result={}
for key in dict1.keys():
    for item in dict1.items():
        if key==item[1]:
            if key not in result:
                result[key]=[]
            result[key].append(item[0])
print(result)
output:
{1: [3, 4], 2: [1, 5], 3: [2]}
```

Comment: This is `O(n^2)` though... Still gets it done though

Answer (score 1):

An `O(n)` solution would be:

```
child_parent = {1:2, 3:1, 4:1, 5:2, 1:5, 6:5, 7:2}
parent_children = {}
for child, parent in child_parent.items():
    parent_children.setdefault(parent, []).append(child)
```

giving:

```
{5: [1, 6], 1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 7]}
```

---

And, for ease of evaluation, the data represents the following tree:

```
  2
 / \
7   5
   / \
  6   1
     / \
    3   4
```

Comment: Thank you! Can python display the tree you drew?

Comment: @user3057109 Not natively, but checkout:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675261/displaying-a-tree-in-ascii